# Hotlinking my Cascading Style Sheets

Tags: css

Someone told me that another person was hotlinking my CSS file. I was able to find with them using my CSS file. I'm not fine with them hotlinking my CSS file.

Is there anyway to only allow one single URL to use my css file?

I asked the person to stop and told them "you can take it and host it elsewhere", but it seems that they won't listen. I decided to change their background to something borderline nsfw, but that still didn't stop them from doing it again. I could start putting goatse and such, but that is going to be wasting my time.

Comment: Tell something more about your environment (php, asp.net, pure html)? What about the web server (iis, apache)?

Comment: XSS their site by injecting some code and save your own CSS in another file.

Comment: Change your filename. Make a new file with the same name as the old, and in it add `*:after { content: 'NO HOTLINKING' !important }`. I think the hotlinking will quickly stop.

Comment: As an alternative to goatse; body{ width:expression(alert('This layout was stolen.')); } put it in a separate css file and redirect to this file if referer matches offender using htaccess (see below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use your .htaccess file to restrict the domain.

[Reference 1](http://web.archive.org/web/20130404073343/http://underscorebleach.net/jotsheet/2004/06/htaccess-prevent-hotlinking)

Reference 2 http://www.globinch.com/2011/04/13/prevent-hotlinking-of-image-script-css-etc-using-htaccess/

Comment: Both links broken by now.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the css in php code and check the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

You can block access folders or files using server settings - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324066 - but if you are in a hosted environment you may not be able to change these settings - you may have to make a request to your host.

Answer (score -1):

If your site is (or supports) PHP, you could put your CSS into a PHP file and include that in the files that need it. Then it would be safe from hot inclusion.