# How to find out who is using my code?

Tags: html

I suspect that someone has copy-pasted my website HTML and is using it as their own. How can I find out who it is? Is there any way to track them down?

I know that I can reverse-image search.

Is there a way to search the internet by webpage html fragments?

If they didn't rehost my resources, is there a way to check who is hotlinking my CSS or JS, if anyone? (what this person mentioned but didn't explain [Hotlinking my Cascading Style Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563721/hotlinking-my-cascading-style-sheets) )

Comment: In your webserver logs, you may be able to see the referrer for any hotlinked resources

Comment: Here's a link for that http://www.activewebhosting.com/faq/web-hotlinkcheck.html

Comment: Do you have the URl they are operating from>

Comment: No, I don't have the URI, the goal is to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the request body fields, assuming that they're stealing your server's bandwith. You can also write a crawler that tries to match your html with other but It won't be reliable. Maybe you can use Google to find specific html blocks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_hacking