# How To Secure .CSS .JS Files

Tags: php, html, xml, .htaccess

How can i Secure my `.CSS .JS` and Other `Site Content` if anyone want to use my links another site how to stop request.
It's Possible only work on my site not on other site like `Crossdomain.xml` Protection.

I already Tried This Code But Not Working
`RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)?getplay\.pk/ [NC]
 RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|gif|bmp|png|css|js)       http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/2885/hotlinking.jpg [L]`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? People can always just save those file and use them, regardless what you do. You can never protect them against that (since they need to be able to download them to use them with your site, to start with). Do you have secrets hidden in your client side files? :o

Comment: You can prevent [hotlinking](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess10.shtml), but that's it. You can obfuscate JS code to help make it more difficult to read. People can go to your site and just save and copy the JS and CSS. Nothing you can do about that. It's the internet.

Comment: Even standard hotlink protection causes more problems than it solves

Comment: @MagnusEriksson @Panama Jack Sir some one using my site direcly like this `http://example.com/mycss.css` and others and my site is loaded and lost bandwith

Comment: @PanamaJack Sir I already try this 
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)?example\.com/ [NC]`
`RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|gif|bmp|png|css|js)$` `http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/2885/hotlinking.jpg [L]`

Comment: Please update your question with what you've tried, instead of a comment.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson okay sir Thanks for Reply

Comment: You can always check this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563721/hotlinking-my-cascading-style-sheets ... but are you sure someone really is hotlinking your static content (css, js and other site content) while having so much traffic that it affects your bandwidth? Sounds strange...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sir My site Traffic is 30k Daily and Pageview 150k But I have seen Some Pepoles Using My css and Js File directly if They are Copied then No Problem But Using Directly with my link

Comment: Are you seeing this in Google Analytics? GA doesn't track hotlinked files. Having 30k visitors and 150k page views only means that people are looking at more than one page per visit.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sir Google Analytics not showing this But I visited a site but when i see site source they are using my site source directly css .js and others

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sir Thanks For Your Suggestion Please can you guide me how can i block IP address in .htaccess

Comment: Sorry. That was actually a brain fart from me. That won't work, since it's their visitors that will download the files, not the site... anyway, did you check that dup-link I left in a couple of comments back?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes i visited this link but i'm confuse they work for me ?

Answer (score 0):

That's called "hotlinking". To prevent these we can use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?simonita.org [NC]
RewriteRule \.(css|js|jpg|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

That code will prevent another site to hotlinking my JavaScript, css, jpg, gif

For testing, access http://simonita.org/test.html. You will warn with 2 alert from 2 different javascript.

Then CTRL+U to see page source:

```
    <script src="http://simonita.org/test.js"></script>
    <script src="http://simonita.org/stackoverflow/test-notallow.js"></script>
```

Now, copy that HTML code to your localhost. You will know if you can only run first script, but cant run second script. run test.html from your localhost, and open your browser console/firebug it will say:

> "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - h*tp://simonita.org/stackoverflow/test-notallow.js"

Why? I fill blank/empty in "rootFolder/.htaccess" because I decide to not rule anything here, so you can hotlinking every file I have, in this case "test.js"

but I fill prevent hotlinking script in "rootFolder/stackoverflow/.htaccess"
so you cannot hotlinking any javascript in "stackoverflow" folder, in this case "test-notallow.js"

You can easy create your own .htaccess for hotlinking from this site http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/

Comment: My site Preffer Link is http i have no ssl and my like is not include www so what i can do

Comment: Important note, if you block access to json and xml, you won't be able to serve any API, where the end point uses json or xml-file endings. You also block google bots from accessing `sitemap.xml` (which is a bad thing). I would remove those and add jpg, gif and png instead.

Comment: @SyedAliRazaNaqvi - You can use this anyway. `(s)?` means that the `s` is optional. This works for both `http` and `https`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay sir Let Me Try

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sir This Code is Not working I have Place this code in .htaccess and try with local file still work js and css files

Comment: let me know if this work. if not work, i will help as i can